# Applying SendGrid filters to CodeIgniter emails

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, sendgrid

I'm trying to integrate SendGrid with my CodeIgniter application to send transactional emails. I've been able to send plain text emails, using the native email library in CodeIgniter and the SendGrid API with this code provided by SendGrid documentation:

```
<?php
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->initialize(array(
  'protocol' => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  'smtp_user' => 'sendgridusername',
  'smtp_pass' => 'sendgridpassword',
  'smtp_port' => 587,
  'crlf' => "\r\n",
  'newline' => "\r\n"
));

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');
$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
$this->email->send();

echo $this->email->print_debugger();
?>
```

In my version, I've filled in all the parameters, so this works.

What I am trying to do, but haven't been able to, is to apply a filter to the email with a template_id. I've designed a template in SendGrid and want these emails to be sent with that design. How do I tell SendGrid to apply the template?

PHP version: 7,
CodeIgniter version: 3